# Spring data jpa custom repository with pageable

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I created custom repository and one method in it. I would like to add pageable object to that query in order to limit items returned.

I created additional method that will extract only selected page from all items. But problem is if i have 50000 items, i would need to get them all and then get just selected page out of them which is very bad for performance.

```
public List<Team> findTeamsForUser(long userId, long statusId, TeamCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select team from Team team join TeamMember teamMember on teamMember.team.id=team.id where 
            teamMember.user.id=" + userId + " AND teamMember.status.id=" + statusId);

    if(criteria!=null) {
        if (criteria.getGameId() != null) {
            sb.append(" AND team.game.id IN " + criteria.getGameId().getIn().toString().replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")"));
        }
    }

    sb.append(" ORDER BY team.createdDate DESC");

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sb.toString());
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I would like to include somehow Pageable parameter into this query so i get only limited items.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you want, do you just want to `LIMIT` the number of returned results or do you want something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setMaxResults()` and  `setFirstResult()` on the `Query` to restrict the number of records and the offset of the first returned record.

`setMaxResults()` is equivalent to `LIMIT` where `setFirstResult()` is equivalent to `OFFSET` in SQL.

Combining `Query` with  `Pageable` from spring data , the codes looks like :

```java
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql.toString());
query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
query.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
```

Assuming each time you want to return 10 records .The `Pageable` for each page is

```java
Pageable page1 = PageRequest.of(0, 10);  //Page 1 , offset=0  , limit=10
Pageable page2 = PageRequest.of(10, 10);  //Page 2 , offset=10 , limit=10
Pageable page3 = PageRequest.of(20, 10);  //Page 3 , offset=20 , limit=10
....
......
Pageable pageN = PageRequest.of((n-1)*10, 10);  //Page N , offset=(N-1)*10 , limit=10
```

Comment: That solves part of issue. But after i execute query i get List<Team>, but i would need to return to FE Page<Team>, how can i do that ?

Comment: `return new PageImpl(teamList, pageable , total)` where total is the total number of record in all pages . If FE does not need this information ,you can simply set it to anything